# Утечка памяти, в чем может быть дело?

Tags: node.js

Скрипт подключает бота на сервер Майнкрафт. Если боту не удается зайти два раза - он ребутает контейнер.

Проверил в процессах (top) - течет нода. Однако, не могу понять пока что может вызывать этот эффект.

```
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const {
    exec
} = require("child_process");

var interval = 20
var count = 0

    console.log("Запущен скрипт: " + new Date().toLocaleString())

    async function doStuff() {

    if (count > 1) {
        console.log("Ребут: " + new Date().toLocaleString())
        count = 0
        //какой-то код, который не влияет.
    } else {

        count++

        var botName = "Arkadii7318"

            const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
            host: "play.minecraft.ru",
            port: 25570,
            username: botName,
            version: '1.12.2'
        });

        bot.on('login', login => {
            count = 0
            setTimeout(() => bot.end(), 3000)
        })

    }

}

let checking = setInterval(() => doStuff(), interval * 1000);
```

Comment: Видимо, bot.end делает не то, что вы ожидаете. Например, не отписывается от события login и продолжает жить в памяти =)

Comment: @vp_arth хм, я думал что когда я пересоздаю бота, то он в любом случае должен удаляться.

Comment: @vp_arth сделал once вместо on, наблюдаю) Пока вроде не переполняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, аккуратнее было бы написать так:

```
// @ts-check
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');

const delayValue = 20 * 1000;
let timer;
let count = 0;

/** @type {import('mineflayer').BotOptions} */
const bot_credentials = {
  host: 'play.minecraft.ru',
  port: 25570,
  username: 'Arkadii7318',
  version: '1.12.2'
};


async function doStuff() {
  if (count > 1) {
    await restartContainer();
    count = 0;
    return;
  }

  count++;
  try {
    await botHealthCheck();
    count--;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('fail: ', err);
  }
}

async function botHealthCheck() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('TIMED_OUT')), 5 * 1000);

      const bot = mineflayer.createBot(bot_credentials);
      bot.once('login', () => {
        resolve();
        bot.quit();
      });
      bot.once('error', reject);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

async function restartContainer() {
  console.log("Ребут: " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  return Promise.resolve();
}


timer = setInterval(doStuff, delayValue);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сейчас обмозгую код и испытаю.

Comment: @keltkelt ещё, по уму, надо избавиться от `setInterval`, а каждый новый таймер делать через `setTimeout` в конце `doStuff`

Comment: Действительно память не кушал, но почему-то застал его три или четыре раза ребутающим сервак через минуту. Я не до конца разобрался в коде. Возможно задержка в ожидании входа сыграла роль, на тот момент были паузы в логине.

Comment: И много ошибок TIMED_OUT было

Comment: В общем, насколько я понял, бот не успевал зайти на сервак, из-за этого копился Count и были ребуты. Увеличу время с 5 секунд на большее. Правда я пока не понял, зачем count-- делать, а не сбрасывать в 0 при удачном логине. В общем я поменял декремент на 0 и убрал проверку TIMED OUT, так как бот и сам ее в error может возвращать. Тестирую.

Comment: 1) я бы сказал, что если за 5 секунд логин не удался то сервер не доступен, с высокой вероятностью 2) при использовании подхода с `setInterval` возможна одновременная работа нескольких healthCheck-ов (никто не следит за тем сколько их сейчас запущено), а это непосредственно влияет на счётчик

Comment: А на всякий случай, не влияет ли то, что я перезагружаю сервер в функции restartContainer() перед возвратом промиса? Он поднимается еще какое-то время, на по идее не больше 15-20 секунд (это докер-сервис)

Comment: правильнее реогранизовать код так: убрать setInterval, в конце выполнения функции doStuff вызывать `setTimeout(doStuff, ...)` - в таком случае постановка следующей задачи проверки здоровья выполнится при завершении текущей задачии. функция restartContainer должна резолвится только тогда когда докер перезапустился. такими вот изменениями мы достигнем того, что рестарт докера не будет воспринят как отсутсвие соединения с сервером

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! А есть ли догадки, что в моем коде могло кушать память? И дело в том, что я не могу отследить когда он перезапустился, так как просто отправляю в консоль команду перезапуска через exec. Поэтому и поставил в своем скрипте интервал в 20сек.

Comment: вам в первом комментарии объяснил vp_arth: вы создаёте бота в переменной `bot`, вызывая метод `.on` создаёте слушателя в котором `bot` продолжает существовать из-за замыкания. иногда это событие не вызывается и объекты продолжают существовать в памяти. возможно вызов `.end` не делает отписку слушателей. короче, `.once` решает

Comment: Да я вот просто заменил on на once, но утечка продолжилась. Спасибо за ответ, проверю еще раз и пошевелю мозгами.....